# Using ASP.NET Membership Provider authentincation in a WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-membership, wcf-security

Is there a way to use the same username and password from the membership provider for a WCF service authentication? if so, which binding does it supports? I need to extract a profile variable from the user currently calling the service. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically any binding that accepts username/password as client credentials for message security can be configured to use the ASP.NET membership provider.

Check out this MSDN docs on [how to use the ASP.NET Membership provider in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) - you need to configure your binding for client credentials of type "UserName"

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
  <!-- Set up a binding that uses UserName as the client credential type -->
    <binding name="MembershipBinding">
      <security mode ="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType ="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and the service to use ASP.NET Membership for user authentication:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="AspNetMembership">
     <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication 
             userNamePasswordValidationMode ="MembershipProvider" 
             membershipProviderName ="SqlMembershipProvider"/>
     </serviceCredentials>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

and of course, you have to apply this service behavior to your services when configuring them!

```
<services>
   <service name="YourService" behaviorConfiguration="AspNetMembership">
   ....
   </service>
</services>
```

The UserName client credential type is supported by basicHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding, netTcpBinding - so pretty much all the usual suspects.

Comment: is it possible to use username with basicHttpBinding without using https? Also, if i use wsHttpBinding, is https mandatory?

Comment: If you're using username/pwd, WCF wants a secure link - so you must use https (since you cannot use message-based encryption). And no: you can absolutely use wsHttpBinding without https - as long as you can encrypt the messages, e.g. by having a certificate available

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584198/authentication-service-using-wcf ?