# Azure WCF Validation

Tags: wcf, authentication, azure

I'm building a web service on Azure.  I need to authenticate the users preferably with usernames and passwords in my database, but to be honest, I'll do it with the easiest and simplest way.  Azure is pretty easy to use and I'm not sure why I'm struggling to find and documentation on how to secure my web service.  Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you  want to authenticate users with username and password I'd give MembershipProvider a try.

[Using ASP.NET Membership Provider authentincation in a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615316/using-asp-net-membership-provider-authentincation-in-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0):

Search for wcf security. Azure will just host your service, but the development part is up to you.

Take a look at this msdn links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx